# Django saving modelformset_factory

Tags: django, formview

When saving the formset, it is not validating and respecting the model fields that I have made unique and therefore renders an Integrity Error should I duplicate fields deliberately to test it.

**My guess is that the formsets themselves validate correctly, but as the unique field is something I have to assign during the save(commit=False) process it never gets validated. Does that make sense?**

Is there something I am missing please?

My code:

```
class ClientCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.case = Case.objects.get(pk=kwargs['case_pk'])
        self.num_clients = self.case.number_clients
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

template_name = 'clients/client_form.html'
form_class = modelformset_factory(Client, ClientForm,
                                  min_num=2, max_num=2, extra=0,
                                  validate_max=True, validate_min=True,
                                  can_delete=False)

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs["queryset"] = Client.objects.none()
    return kwargs

def form_valid(self, form_class):
    form_class.save()

    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        ctx['inlines'] = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
    else:
        ctx['inlines'] = self.form_class()
    return ctx

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('client-list',
                   kwargs={'case_pk': self.kwargs['case_pk']})
```

I appreciate that formview is *really* supposed to be used for single form saving, but this does actually work correctly when not having duplicate unique items.

Many thanks

EDIT:::

This is my function based version that also suffers from the same issue:

```
@login_required
def client(request, case_pk):
    template_name = 'clients/client_form.html'
    case = get_object_or_404(Case,
                         pk=case_pk, adviser__company__account=request.user
                         )

    formset_class = modelformset_factory(Client, ClientForm,
                                     min_num=case.number_clients,
                                     max_num=case.number_clients, extra=0,
                                     validate_max=True, validate_min=True,
                                     can_delete=False)

formset = formset_class(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    # check all formsets valid
    if all(form.is_valid() for form in formset):
        for f in formset:
            if f.is_valid():
                form = f.save(commit=False)
                form.case = case
                f.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('client-create',
                                            kwargs={'case_pk': case_pk}))

return render(request, template_name, {
    'inlines': formset,
    'case': case,
    'breadcrumbs': 'Family & Dependants'
})
```

Client Form:

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ['prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_names', 'last_name',
              'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'residence', 'address_1',
              'address_2', 'address_3', 'city', 'postcode', 'telephone',
              'marital_status', 'widowed_date_of_death',
              'have_will', 'why_changing', 'existing_poa', 'dependant', ]
```

Client Model is large so this is the unique clause:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('case', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                       'date_of_birth', )
```

Comment: Have you considered using just a function based view for this? It might be easier to debug

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed the `Client` model and `ClientForm`, and an example of the invalid data you are using to test.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I have added the function based equivalent that also suffers from the same issue, the form and part of the client model.

Answer (score 0):

modelformset_factory appears to not respect database level constraints. Therefore, the check has to be done before saving the form.

They way to do this is by overriding the BaseModelFormSet class.

Solution here: [Save multiple objects with a unique attribute using Django formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484564/save-multiple-objects-with-a-unique-attribute-using-django-formset)