# Django admin inline unique constraint violation on edit

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a form with inline. A related model has a unique together constraint (parent_id, number). I have an entity with two children

```
parent_id | number |
        1 |      1 |
        1 |      2 |
```

and I am trying to edit these children in one operation to the state

```
parent_id | number |
        1 |      2 |
        1 |      3 |
```

When I am saving I have an error on the first entry: 
`Child with this parent_id and number already exists.`

However, if I firstly edit the second entry:

```
parent_id | number |
        1 |      1 |
        1 |      3 |
```

and then the first

```
parent_id | number |
        1 |      2 |
        1 |      3 |
```

in two separate actions, it works fine.

ParentAdmin definition

```
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BaseForm

    inlines = [LevelExerciseInline]
```

ChildInline definition

```
class ChildInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = BaseForm

    model = Child
    extra = 3
```

Comment: Is this parent_id primary_key ?

Comment: Could you paste your code for "and I am trying to edit these children in one operation to the state" - are you using `queryset.update` in combination with `F()`? Obviously, right now, your code issues subsequent statements and the DB rejects it correctly.

Comment: @NVS for parent table, yes. For child table, no.

Comment: @Risadinha I am not understand what are u talking about. I believe that update action generated by django-admin. I haven't done any special code for that, just defined model, admin form and inline.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Django Admin inlines, the following will not be the case:

> and I am trying to edit these children in one operation to the state

Inlines are part of the complete form, they will be processed in order of their appearance in the form. Thus, even if you change them "in one action", meaning that you change them during one form POST, Django will still save these related objects one by one:

The first inline in the list is saved, and it tries to save parent_id 1 with number 2 while there is still parent_id 2 with number 2 in the database.

Specifically, `formset.save()` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L655) is called, with the following code.

Note: here, "form" is a part of the actual HTML form (it's just the name of the variables, do not confuse it).

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """Saves model instances for every form, adding and changing instances
    as necessary, and returns the list of instances.
    """
    if not commit:
        self.saved_forms = []

        def save_m2m():
            for form in self.saved_forms:
                form.save_m2m()
        self.save_m2m = save_m2m
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
```

As you can see, each inline is saved in a loop once save_m2m is called. The array is sorted in order of appearance in the form.

This is less about the Django Admin and more a question on whether it is even possible on a database level, though. The only possiblity that could work would be a transaction but even then - postgresql for example would not allow it, unless the constraint is set to DEFERRED:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104987/avoid-unique-violation-in-atomic-transaction

Postgresql documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html

So, to change the behavior, you would need:

- change the unique constraint to be `DEFERRED` (at least during the transaction) by calling raw SQL (Django does not support this, see [How can I set a table constraint "deferrable initially deferred" in django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891574/how-can-i-set-a-table-constraint-deferrable-initially-deferred-in-django-model))
- override `formset.save` to use `transaction.atomic`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, if I understand correctly if I change children records in backward order (like was [(parent_id, 2), (parent_id, 1)], became [(parent_id, 3), (parent_id, 2)]) it would work. Funny thing it doesn't, so I think the real problem is quite different.

Comment: Only if you save in between. If you change the numbers in whatever order and only save once afterwards, the only order that matters is the order in which the inlines appear in the form (on the page).

Comment: @Risadina I made them appear in correct order. It was (parent_id, 2), (parent_id, 1) and I made (parent_id, 3), (parent_id, 2). If you are correct, then first would be saved (parent_id, 3) and at the moment when (parent_id, 2) is saved there is no other record with (parent_id, 2) so it should work fine. But it doesn't.

I also had a deep look into the code, it fails on Django validation level it isn't even trying to save an object.