# SQLAlchemy + asyncpg doesn't catch deferred exception

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I am now using SQLAlchemy 1.4, asyncpg and FastAPI, and I wrote the code like this:

```py
    try:
        cr: sa.engine.CursorResult = await conn.execute(stmt)
        return schemas.UserGroup(
            **user_group_dict,
            id=cr.inserted_primary_key[0],
        )
    except sa.exc.IntegrityError:
        raise exceptions.conflict_exception()
```

UserGroup table references User and Group tables and has a unique key constraint (user, group)

```py
user_groups = sa.Table(
    "auth_user_groups",
    metadata,
    sa.Column(
        "id",
        sa.BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
    ),
    sa.Column(
        "user_id",
        sa.BigInteger,
        sa.ForeignKey("auth_user.id"),
    ),
    sa.Column(
        "group_id",
        sa.BigInteger,
        sa.ForeignKey("auth_group.id"),
    ),
    sa.UniqueConstraint("user_id", "group_id"),
)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.auth_user_groups
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('auth_user_groups_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    group_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_group_id_94350c0c_uniq UNIQUE (user_id, group_id),
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_group_id_97559544_fk_auth_group_id FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_group (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```

When I try to insert a duplicated record, it works fine.

However, when I try to insert a record with fk which does not exist in User and Group, I cannot catch the exception.

```
2022-06-14 01:02:50,978 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/projects/fastapi-from-dj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 366, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/test/projects/fastapi-from-dj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
...
  File "/home/test/projects/fastapi-from-dj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 685, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
  File "/home/test/projects/fastapi-from-dj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 741, in commit
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "/home/test/projects/fastapi-from-dj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 682, in _handle_exception
    raise translated_error from error
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.ForeignKeyViolationError'>: insert or update on table "auth_user_groups" violates foreign key constraint "auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(15) is not present in table "auth_user".
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Of course, I tried to catch exception with `asyncpg.exceptions.ForeignKeyViolationError` and `Exception as e`, but I failed.

Thank you.

Comment: So your question is essentially: "Why is a violation of the UNIQUE contraint (which is IMMEDIATE) is being caught while a violation of one of the FK constraints (which are DEFERRED) is not being caught?"

Comment: @GordThompson,
Exactly.
UNIQUE constraint is being caught, but FK constraint is not being caught.
What is difference between IMMEDIATE and DEFERRED?
How can I catch both of them?

Comment: ref: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) - "IMMEDIATE constraints are checked at the end of each statement. DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction commit."

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to catch both of them if you force the commit within the `try:` block.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for your help. I decided to alter my table FK constraints with "IMMEDIATE" modes. Now the exception is being caught as I expected. I posted my answer by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gord Thompson's comment

I was able to solve my problem by altering the table FK constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.auth_user_groups
    DROP CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_id;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.auth_user_groups
    ADD CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

As a result, now I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.auth_user_groups
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('auth_user_groups_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    group_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_group_id_94350c0c_uniq UNIQUE (user_id, group_id),
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_group_id_97559544_fk_auth_group_id FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_group (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

It does not have the line: `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

I am now using the tables which were migrated by Django so that FastAPI uses them as a REST API.

I believe that the following answer link will be useful for Django users:

[How can I set a table constraint "deferrable initially deferred" in django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891574/how-can-i-set-a-table-constraint-deferrable-initially-deferred-in-django-model/56644496#56644496)

Thank you.